# One To Many Value Table, How to default to a single row when no join found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some tables laid out like the example below. I am looking to create a query that gets returns all a list of users and their emails. I am running into an issue where my joins either filter out an entire user or create duplicate rows.

User Table

| UserName | UserId |
| --- | --- |
| Batman | 10 |
| Superman | 11 |

UserContact Table

| UserId | ContactNBr |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 200 |
| 11 | 300 |
| 10 | 400 |
| 11 | 500 |

ContactLine Table

| ContactNbr | ContactLineNbr | ContactType | ContactCategory | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 1 | Street | Home | 101st |
| 200 | 2 | City | Home | Gothem |
| 300 | 1 | City | Work | Metropolis |
| 300 | 2 | Street | Work | Main st. |
| 400 | 1 | District | Work | 1 |
| 400 | 2 | City | Work | Gothem |
| 500 | 1 | City | Home | Krypton |

**Query1**

```sql
Select u.UserName, c.Value FROM Usr u
JOIN UserContact uc ON
    u.UserId = uc.UserId
JOIN ContactLine c ON
    c.ContactNbr = uc.ContactNbr AND
    c.ContactType = 'Email' AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
```

**Query1 Results**

| UserName | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Superman | super@man.com |

*We are missing Batman*

**Query2**

```sql
Select u.UserName, c.Value FROM Usr u
JOIN UserContact uc ON
    u.UserId = uc.UserId
LEFT JOIN ContactLine c ON
    c.ContactNbr = uc.ContactNbr AND
    c.ContactType = 'Email' AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
```

**Results**

| UserName | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Superman | super@man.com |
| Superman | Null |
| Batman | Null |
| Batman | Null |

*We are duplicating rows*

I could filter on distinct but In my real query, there are more joins and more columns that could be duplicate BUT also valid. Is there a way to make this query return the joined email OR a null value for only one of the lookup table values?

| UserName | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Superman | super@man.com |
| Batman | Null |

Here is an updated [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1faa528b785607bc91e48f7932b6fc45)
Thanks @MatBailie for showing me this awesome tool!

Comment: With that data and query, changing the last join to a `LEFT JOIN` can ***not*** cause the behaviour described.  For there to be 3 Superman rows before the `LEFT JOIN`, the first `INNER JOIN` must have created the multiple rows, or your query/data doesn't match the description.

Comment: Proof that your final query already does what you want *(with typos corrected)* : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65328b058b0ff0280c8a5c0d3abc8b32

Comment: @MatBailie you are correct, I am missing one table that makes this query much more difficult allow me to update the question. I'll let you know once I have updated it

Comment: @MatBailie Updated with the tricky join that makes this a little harder. I have updated your DBFiddle and it is now returning a result  similar to the one that I am receiving on my real table. I apologize for overlooking that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as it is currently worded...

- No need for sub-queries
- Just use `()`'s or `RIGHT JOIN`

Example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ce519a991b79d4a9cd7e8ce5dfc821a

```
Select
  u.UserName, c.Value
FROM
  Usr u
LEFT JOIN
  (
    UserContact uc
  INNER JOIN
    ContactLine c
      ON  c.ContactNbr      = uc.ContactNbr
      AND c.ContactType     = 'Email'
      AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
  )
    ON u.UserId = uc.UserId
```

Or...

```
Select
  u.UserName, c.Value
FROM
  UserContact uc
INNER JOIN
  ContactLine c
    ON  c.ContactNbr      = uc.ContactNbr
    AND c.ContactType     = 'Email'
    AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
RIGHT JOIN
  Usr u
    ON u.UserId = uc.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SubQuery for the data giving us problems

```
WITH UserEmail AS (
        Select u.UserName, c.Value FROM Usr u
    JOIN UserContact uc ON
        u.UserId = uc.UserId
    JOIN ContactLine c ON
        c.ContactNbr = uc.ContactNbr AND
        c.ContactType = 'Email' AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
)
```

The results of this query will be:

| UserId | UserName | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Superman | super@man.com |

Now, whenever you need to map employee email to a user LEFT Join on our sub query. Any Results not in the sub query will return null

```
WITH UserEmail AS (
        Select u.UserName, c.Value FROM Usr u
    JOIN UserContact uc ON
        u.UserId = uc.UserId
    JOIN ContactLine c ON
        c.ContactNbr = uc.ContactNbr AND
        c.ContactType = 'Email' AND c.ContactCategory = 'Work'
)
SELECT 
    ue.Email,
    cfh.UserId,
    cfh.Total AS NumberOfCalls
FROM CallsForHelp cfh
Left Join UserEmail ue ON
    cfh.UserId = ue.UserId
```

| Email | UserId | NumberOfCalls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Super@man.com | 11 | 3043000 |
| *null* | 10 | 5023000 |

Comment: Your self-answer does not match your original or your revised question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want `left join`:

```
SELECT u.UserName, c.Value
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     UserContact uc
     ON u.UserId = uc.UserId LEFT JOIN
     Contact c
     ON c.ContactNmbr = uc.ContactNbr AND
        c.ContactType = 'Email';
```

Note that *both* joins need to be `LEFT JOIN`s if you want to keep all users.

Comment: The OP's assertions are false.  The OP's query does ***not*** give the results described for the given input.  In fact it actually gives the correct/required results, without any changes *(other than typos)*... Example/Proof : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65328b058b0ff0280c8a5c0d3abc8b32